# Count num of values within range on every Nth cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

We have a data-set generated by an HR system of staff times, which isn't in the most helpful of formats.

We need to count the # of staff who start work before 10.00, and split those counts by week number (1-4) and day (Sun-Sat).

Every group of rows (1-4) is an individual.

Here's an example day's data:

`Week  Start
1   -
2   10:00
3   09.00
4   09.55
1   09:25
2   10.00
3   10:25
4   10.25
1   09:25
2   09.55
3   08:00
4   10.00
1   10:25
2   09.25
3   09:25
4   10.15
1   10.00
2   08:25
3   09.45
4   11:25`

So I can count the occurence of start times before 10am on the entire column with:

`=COUNTIFS(L5:L203,">=00:30",L5:L203,"<=10:00")`

but to do separate counts for every 4th row (so sum all for ones on week 1, all on week 2, etc) is beyond me.

I tried the following after searching similar questions, but it didn't work:

`=COUNTIFS((MOD(ROW(L5:L203),5)=0),">=00:30",(MOD(ROW(L5:L203),5)=0),"<=10:00")`

Ideally I'd be able to put values into a table with a count for week 1 on Sunday, week 2 on Sunday, week 1 on Monday, and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count the weeks use:

```
=COUNTIFs(B$2:B$21,"<=10:00",$A$2:$A$21,"=1")

=COUNTIFs(B$2:B$21,"<=10:00",$A$2:$A$21,"=2")
```

Changing =1, =2, =3, =4 for each weeks count. If column B is Monday and column C is Tuesday, you can drag the above formulas right across the row to get the weekly counts for other days.